# how do I implement func calculation inside struc?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to create an apple watch app that calculates Karvonen value.

When I inserted func calculation into `struct`, I kept receiving the Swift Compiler Error that says:

> [Type "FourthView"does not conform to protocol "View"]

I understood that I should not be calculating inside the `func`, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
struct FourthView: View{

    @Binding var fourthScreenShown:Bool
    //@State var RHR:Int
    //@State var weight:Int
    @State var Age:Int
    @State var ExerciseIT = 0.3
    @State var ConstantNumber = 220
    @State var RHR = 68
    
    func karvonen(cn: Int, rhr: Int, age: Int, ei:Double) -> Double {
        return Double((cn-age-rhr)) * ei + Double(rhr)
        let output = karvonen(cn: ConstantNumber, rhr: RHR, age: Age, ei: ExerciseIT)
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Text("Your Kar is")
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                Text("\(output)")
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var body` has to exist at the top level of the `struct` for it to conform to `View`. Right now, you have `var body` *inside* your `func`.

```
struct FourthView: View{
    
    @Binding var fourthScreenShown:Bool
    @State var Age:Int
    @State var ExerciseIT = 0.3
    @State var ConstantNumber = 220
    @State var RHR = 68
    
    func karvonen(cn: Int, rhr: Int, age: Int, ei:Double) -> Double {
        return Double((cn-age-rhr)) * ei + Double(rhr)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Your Kar is")
                .font(.system(size: 14))
            Text("\(karvonen(cn: ConstantNumber, rhr: RHR, age: Age, ei: ExerciseIT))")
                .font(.system(size: 40))
        }
    }
    
}
```

Another equivalent version (maybe useful if you have to use the result in multiple places):

```
var body: some View {
    let output = karvonen(cn: ConstantNumber, rhr: RHR, age: Age, ei: ExerciseIT)
    VStack{
        Text("Your Kar is")
            .font(.system(size: 14))
        Text("\(output)")
            .font(.system(size: 40))
    }
}
```

---

Unrelated to your issue, but a hint for the future: in Swift, generally, variables/parameters are camel cased. So, your `Age`, `ExerciseIT`, etc would be `age`, `exerciseIT`, etc.

Also, unless you're changing the values, you don't need `@State` in front of all of the parameters. `ConstantNumber`, for example (if the name is accurate), probably doesn't need to be `@State`.